# SQL Code Evaluation stopping a valid transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As part of the company I am working for at the moment I need to create some database upgrade scripts to replace some work of a previous contractor.

The code before the following block runs, creates the new ID column, and then this script looks to populate the values and then drop some columns.

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM   sys.columns 
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp]') 
       AND name = 'Name')
       and 
       EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM   sys.columns 
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp]') 
       AND name = 'Code')
BEGIN
UPDATE
    [Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp]
SET
    CompetencyId = rc.Id
FROM
    [Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp] rlc
INNER JOIN
    [Core.Lookup].ReportCompetency rc
ON 
    rc.Code = rlc.Code and rc.Name = rlc.Name

ALTER TABLE [Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp] DROP COLUMN CODE
ALTER TABLE [Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp] DROP COLUMN [Name]
ALTER TABLE [Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp] DROP COLUMN [Description]

END
GO
```

When running the if exists \ not exists checks and then select getdate() this works perfeclty fine and gives me the result I expect.

However, when I run the code block above I get error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>
> Invalid column name 'Code'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>
> Invalid column name 'Name'.

This script it part of a larger upgrade script and is used in a system calle RoundHouse https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse which is the system chosen by the company.

Prior to the above if exists check,

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sys.columns 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('[Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp]')
AND Name in ('Name','Code')) = 2
```

which also gave the same issue. I have five tables that I need to update and this is going to stop the team from working if I cant resolve this at my next PR

What can I do in order to stop this from causing the upgrade scripts to fail?

EDIT -- The reason I am linking on varchar fields also is because the previous developer did not create relationships between tables, and was just inserting strings into tables rather than relating by ID causing the potential for unlinked \ inconsistent data.

The table edit prior to this creates the new id column, and this script is getting the value and dropping columns that are no longer needed

Comment: From a parsing perspective, once the field has been dropped, the update doesn't parse (regardless of the exists logic). Which version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: @Andrew im am on SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server will parse the whole of the statement prior to execution, so the exists check does not protect you from the update being parsed. If the column has already been dropped, that makes the statement invalid and you get a parse error. The update statement would have to be executed as dynamic SQL, sp_execute basically so that the varchar of the update is not directly parsed.

For SQL Server 2016 and above the drop column can be protected a bit more as well:

```
ALTER TABLE [Central].[Core.Report].[ReportLessonComp] DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS CODE
```

Comment: its the update statement where the first failuer occurs, so although this would work for the drop, I cant get passed the update

Comment: I was just of the opinion that i would have to write dynamic SQL too...  :(

Comment: @SimonPrice - afraid so.